# Значение громкости в dB в QMediaPlayer? Python Qt

Tags: python, qt, qmediaplayer

Создаю аудио-плеер в PyQt и столкнулся с следующей проблемой: мне нужно отображать в реальном времени текущее значение громкости аудио в dB. В QMediaPlayer есть только изменение общей громкости дорожки от 0 до 100. Есть какие-нибудь решения по этому вопросу?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudio.html#State-enum

Comment: Как вы себе это представляете? Это же все зависит от кучи параметров - ЦАП, предусилитель, усилитель, сами динамики в конце концов